# Getting cURL call to work in PHP -XPOST

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the follwing curl call which works on linux.

`curl -XPOST 'https://site.site.com/1.0/projects/1626/inbox/search.json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: randomauthorizationcodethatisactuallymuchlongerandmorerandom' --data '{}'`

This call works when called in the terminal. I've tried to recreate it using PHP functions and I'm not having any luck. This is what I have done

```
$accessToken = 'randomauthorizationcodethatisactuallymuchlongerandmorerandom';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://site.site.com/1.0/projects/1626/inbox/search.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Authorization: ' . $accessToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

I've been messing with this one for days and I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: did you get ant error?

Comment: Yes, it returned a 415 error saying it was a bad request.

Comment: add `HEADER` `'Content-Type: application/json'`. and Try